# Why tuples unpacking is not working with Selenium WebDriverWait?

Tags: python, selenium, tuples, appium, webdriverwait

How is it possible to unpack tuples with Selenium `WebDriverWait`?

Why this code is not working?

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        
    editprofile_button = (By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Edit profile info\"]")
    
    def profile_page_should_be_visible(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,20)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(*Test.editprofile_button))
        assert self.driver.find_element(*Test.editprofile_button).is_displayed()
```

But if I write the function like this, then everything is working with WebdriverWait:

```
def profile_page_should_be_visible(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,20)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text=\"Edit profile info\"]")))
    assert self.driver.find_element(*Test.editprofile_button).is_displayed()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presence_of_element_located`, as most of the other expected conditions, is locating the WebElement on `__call__`

```
class presence_of_element_located(object):
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
```

where `self.locator` is the tuple.

```
def _find_element(driver, by):
    try:
        return driver.find_element(*by)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        raise e
```

`_find_element` is using `driver.find_element(*by)` where `by` is the tuple. As you can see, the tuple is already being unpacked internally.

You can use `Test.editprofile_button` without unpacking it

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(Test.editprofile_button))
```